# error while setting conditional value in rust using format in string

Tags: rust

I have an issue related to conditional value to a string in rust, if I remove format() everything runs fine but I have no idea how to implement this with format.

```
 let value =
                    if matcha.sugar {
                        format!("Hello {} your matcha is ready at {}ºC with sugar", self.client, matcha.temp);
                    }
                    else {
                        format!("Hello {} your matcha is ready at {}ºC without sugar", self.client, matcha.temp);
                    }.to_string();
```

Error Message:

```
    "message": "the method `to_string` exists for unit type `()`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied\n\nmethod cannot be called on `()` due to unsatisfied trait bounds\n\nnote: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:\n      `(): std::fmt::Display`\n      which is required by `(): std::string::ToString`",
    "source": "rustc",
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 60,
            "startColumn": 23,
            "endLineNumber": 60,
            "endColumn": 32,
            "message": "method cannot be called on `()` due to unsatisfied trait bounds",
            
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trailing semicolons make expressions evaluate to ()
You need to remove the ; after the format!(...)s
Also, the to_string() is useless because format!(...) already give you Strings, you would just allocate a new one for nothing

by Giuschi#7708